# HTML Slideshow Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

So I'm learning to create HTML Slideshows using CSS & Javascript. :D

I try to do this tutorial available at W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/7Bw2RfP.jpg?1" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">50. Assetto Corsa<br>
Genre: Action RPG, Hack n Slash<br>
Year: 2013<br>
Platforms: Windows, Xbox One, PS4<br>
Developer: Kunos Simulazioni<br>
Mode: Single-Player, Multi-Player</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8nEDMdN.jpg?1" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RINm3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I changed the image sources to the ones at Imgur , for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMtOc.png

1. And when I copy the code into a WYSIWYG editor, it just displays the buttons below but not the images. Why is that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/RINm3.jpg
2. More importantly how do I make the text to appear below the image as opposed to inside the image and change it dynamically when the image also changes?

Answer (score 0):

To try answering part of question 2.

```
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px; 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Try changing this `bottom: 8px;` to a negative number to get the caption below the picture. Be prepared to mess with the size of the slideshow container to make room for the caption.

Comment: Thanks . What about part 1 of the question? When I run the code on Stackoverflow I can see the images, but when I run it in my WYSIWYG editor the images doesn't show up, but only the 3 buttons below.

Comment: @George I assume it's saved as a .html file on your computer. Try opening it directly in some browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Explorer. If it works in the browsers I wouldn't worry much about it not working in your WYSIWYG.